# Possibility of using maven surfire plugin for SOAP webservice tests

Tags: automated-testing, web-service, maven

I have a challenge of using maven surfire plugin for SOAP webservices testing. What I need to check is whether this plugin can be used while running webservices tests in CI environment. I will appreciate any suggestions.

Many thanks for your comments and feedback.

Comment: What language and test library your current SOAP web services tests are using?

Comment: I found you've asked same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946246/possibility-of-using-maven-surfire-plugin-for-soap-webservice-tests. Please, do not cross-post a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites. More explanation and how to migrate questions you can find here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm new at StackExchange and still learning rules here ;) Thanks for sharing link about how to cross-post questions on Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven Surefire plugin can handle any tests written with JUnit or TestNG. This means whatever your JUnit/TestNG are doing, including SOAP Web servce testing, they can be run with Maven Surefire plugin.

Maven Surefire can be used in CI environment (e.g. Jenkins). You just define your CI job with `mvn test` to execute tests.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) which easily integrates into a standard Java / Maven project. You can actually generate the standard JUnit XML report format which most CI tools understand. Or you have the option of integrating 3rd party reports via Maven. The test execution is via the Maven surefire plugin.

And yes, Karate has excellent support for SOAP and XML.

Disclaimer: I am the dev.